# Error when i'm trying to install my own package by pip. Python

Tags: python

When i'm trying to install my package by command:

```
pip install tv_sched_pars-0.1.macosx-10.6-universal.tar.gz
```

gives me error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/5W/5WnKRhNyGe0O6x6IhEkbnE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-dZHBRf-build/setup.py'
```

Package was made by `python setup.py bdist`

And then found in directory `dist`.

Any ideas why do i get it?

There is my package: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15842180/tv_sched_pars-0.1.macosx-10.6-universal.tar.gz

Installation by using `python setup.py install` goes very well...

By the way - I'm using `virtualenv`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either use `bdist_egg` or `sdist`. Only those create artifacts installable by pip / easy_install.